# Display one record at a time in from ArrayList in jsp page

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jsp

I have created a quiz application using spring mvc and displayed all questions at a time passing arraylist as a model attribute and using for each loop in jsp.
Now i want to display one record at each time when user clicked on next/previous.
I have been stuck on this from the past two days i would be happy if someone helped me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please, provide more info, code, stack traces.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `display one record at each time when user clicked on next/previous` not need ArrayList, a plain obejct is enough.

Comment: ArrayList itself contains multiple POJOs .

Comment: I know that. I mean, it's OK to return an object to the front end every time a request is made(next/previous). There's no need to use ArrayList.